# Multiple synchronous url connections cause timeout on Apache Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, httpurlconnection, java-6

I have a server running tomcat 7, and I've noticed that whenever a client performs multiple serial requests to the server (around 10), it stops responding and causes a timeout on the client.

Seeing the server's logs, I've noticed that the server does's even receive the request.

Here is the client implementation:

```
try{
    String http = "...";
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
        http += "?id="+ String.valueOf(i);
        URL url = new URL(http);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        BufferedReader inc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = inc.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        inc.close();
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    br.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```